# _gdbm.error: Database needs recovery -- after running out of storage while fetching api data

Tags: python, database, pickle, gnu

I really don't know how to help myself, being unfamiliar with this kind of error, and not finding anything on the Google landscape really. My last hope is one of you guys since I don't know where else to go with this. I tried reinstalling all libraries and setting up a new venv. For more action I don't trust myself enough in these kinds of things.

The code triggering the error:

```
from wetterdienst import DWDObservationData

observations_daily = DWDObservationData(
    station_ids=station_ids_d,
    parameter=params_daily,
    time_resolution=TimeResolution.DAILY,
    start_date="2015-01-01",
    end_date="2020-10-10",
    tidy_data=True,
    humanize_column_names=True,
)

for df in observations_hourly.collect_data():
    name = str(df.STATION_ID.iloc[0]).strip(".0")
    df.to_csv('./data/hourly/{}.csv'.format(name))
    print('{} done'.format(name))
```

API is found here: https://github.com/earthobservations/wetterdienst

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/main.py", line 83, in <module>
    for df in observations_hourly.collect_data():
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wetterdienst/dwd/observations/api.py", line 178, in collect_data
    df_parameter = self._collect_parameter_from_station(
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wetterdienst/dwd/observations/api.py", line 243, in _collect_parameter_from_station
    df_period = collect_climate_observations_data(
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wetterdienst/dwd/observations/access.py", line 82, in collect_climate_observations_data
    filenames_and_files = download_climate_observations_data_parallel(remote_files)
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wetterdienst/dwd/observations/access.py", line 106, in download_climate_observations_data_parallel
    return list(zip(remote_files, files_in_bytes))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wetterdienst/dwd/observations/access.py", line 124, in _download_climate_observations_data
    return BytesIO(__download_climate_observations_data(remote_file=remote_file))
  File "<decorator-gen-2>", line 2, in __download_climate_observations_data
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 1356, in get_or_create_for_user_func
    return self.get_or_create(
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 954, in get_or_create
    with Lock(
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dogpile/lock.py", line 185, in __enter__
    return self._enter()
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dogpile/lock.py", line 94, in _enter
    generated = self._enter_create(value, createdtime)
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dogpile/lock.py", line 178, in _enter_create
    return self.creator()
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 920, in gen_value
    self.backend.set(key, value)
  File "/Users/sashakaun/PycharmProjects/wetter2.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dogpile/cache/backends/file.py", line 239, in set
    dbm[key] = pickle.dumps(value, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
_gdbm.error: Database needs recovery
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

A GDBM file has been corrupted. You need to use `gdbmtool` to recover the database. Install `gdbmtool` then run

```
gdbmtool FILENAME
```

Where FILENAME is the name of the GDBM database. A prompt will appear, then you can enter

```
gdbmtool> recover summary
```

If the database can be recovered it will display a summary of the recovery results, eg:

```
Recovery succeeded.
Keys recovered: 6870650, failed: 5, duplicate: 0
Buckets recovered: 64830, failed: 2
```